# sql stored procedure loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I need help building a loop in my stored procedure, basically i want it too loop from 2005 till the current year.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testt1]
 as
DECLARE @YearToGet int;
SET @YearToGet = 2005;

WITH Years AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) [Year]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Year]-1 FROM Years WHERE [Year]>@YearToGet
)

SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT DIVISION, DYYYY, SUM(APRICE) AS Sales, SUM(PARTY) AS PAX, SUM(NetAmount) AS NetSales, SUM(InsAmount) 
                      AS InsSales, SUM(CancelRevenue) AS CXSales, SUM(OtherAmount) AS OtherSales, SUM(CXVALUE) AS CXValue
FROM         dbo.B101BookingsDetails AS B101BookingsDetails 


WHERE    Booked <= CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, (SELECT * FROM Years) - Year(getdate()), DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 2, getdate()), 0)))
  and DYYYY = @YearToGet
GROUP BY  DYYYY, DIVISION

ORDER BY DIVISION,  DYYYY




OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- this avoids hitting the recursion limit in the CTE
```

and i could really used a stored procedure website that goes into more detail then just the simple select statements

Comment: my loop isn't working, i want to run the select statement multiple until the year reaches the current year

Comment: First of all: why not just use `YEAR(GETDATE())` instead of the oddball DATENAME() approach..... also: you're never **updating** your `@YearToGet` or `year` value - I would think this ends in either a non-loop or an endless loop....

Comment: So what do you really want to do here?? Try to explain what you're trying to achieve..... this is not clear from just a snippet of code....

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: o damn hahah im retarded, my major problem is i am getting a syntax error at begin

Comment: I want to do a basic loop, but i am not sure on how to do this in a stored procedure. From a syntax standpoint, i have done loops in vb and python and other languages but never in a stored procedure

Comment: If you are trying to select all of the data, you are going to need to insert it into a temporary table at each iteration and then do a select off of that after the loop is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not directly an answer, but the code cannot be posted in a readible fashion in a comment, so I think this should be okay here:

Don't loop in SPs, rather use a CTE to generate the numbers you need.

```
DECLARE @YearToGet int;
SET @YearToGet = 2005;

WITH Years AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) [Year]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Year]-1 FROM Years WHERE [Year]>@YearToGet
)
SELECT * FROM Years -- join here with your query
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- this avoids hitting the recursion limit in the CTE
```

**Edit**: Try this

```
WITH  Years
          AS (
              SELECT DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) [Year]
              UNION ALL
              SELECT [Year]-1
                FROM Years
                WHERE [Year] > @YearToGet
             )
    SELECT DIVISION, DYYYY, SUM(APRICE) AS Sales, SUM(PARTY) AS PAX, SUM(NetAmount) AS NetSales, SUM(InsAmount) AS InsSales, SUM(CancelRevenue) AS CXSales, SUM(OtherAmount) AS OtherSales, SUM(CXVALUE) AS CXValue
      FROM dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
      JOIN Years yr ON DYYYY = yr.[Year]
      WHERE Booked <= CONVERT(int, DATEADD(year, DYYYY-YEAR(GETDATE()), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 2, GETDATE()), 0)))
      GROUP BY DYYYY, DIVISION
      ORDER BY DIVISION, DYYYY
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: so instead of looping i can set @ year to get as many years, but how will it update for next year

Comment: Just join your `SELECT` statement with the `Years` CTE as shown here, or do a subquery if you like better (this would require little change in your query). Your current code is flawed because it will return an arbitrary number of result sets, which is most certainly not what you're after.

Comment: When you're doing SQL always think in SETS instead of row by row (most programming languages). Most, if not all loops in SQL can be rewritten to use only SQL. Loops in SQL are a performance hit.

Comment: Thanks clyc for the support... ;-) - and to add to this, since the advent of recursive CTE's, generating data on the fly to be used for set operations has become very easy and efficient.

Comment: i agree with everything but the easy part i can't even join my statement

Comment: i posted what i tryed up top if you can look at it i got an Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure testt1, Line 13
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: @MHH, edited with a possible solution (can't try it though since I dont have the schema and data).

Comment: @clyc - To be honest a recursive CTE is just a loop with syntactic sugar around it. The set based approach would be to use a permanent auxiliary numbers table IMO. [Jeff Moden claims a while loop is actually more efficient than a recursive CTE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1029197-392-1.aspx#bm1029220)

Comment: @Martin, very true :) I would normally use an auxiliary numbers table as well. I have edited my answer to use something else ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ok written to not use recursive CTE :)
Since you are already storing the year in the B101BookingsDetails table, just get the list of years that is greater than the year you are looking for from there.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testt1
(
    @YearToGet int = 2005
)
AS

    WITH Years AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT DYYYY as year
        FROM    dbo.B101BookingsDetails
        WHERE DYYYY >= @YearToGet
    )   
    SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT DIVISION, DYYYY, SUM(APRICE) AS Sales, SUM(PARTY) AS PAX, SUM(NetAmount) AS NetSales, 
                SUM(InsAmount) AS InsSales, SUM(CancelRevenue) AS CXSales, SUM(OtherAmount) AS OtherSales, SUM(CXVALUE) AS CXValue
        FROM    dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
                INNER JOIN Years
                    ON B101BookingsDetails.DYYYY = Years.Year
        WHERE   Booked  <= CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, Years.Year - Year(getdate()), DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 2, getdate()), 0)))
        GROUP BY DYYYY, DIVISION
```

Comment: what if i wanted to change my booked<= convert(int, @date) but the year would have to be different each time for example if the user puts in 1/5/2011 , it would run the query for 1/5/2010, 1/5/2009,1/5/2008.... or if they put 1/10/2011 it would do 1/10/2010, 1/10/2009 ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment @YearToGet at the end of the loop.